# Creating a thread in via TBB library

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, tbb

I have a code like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <tbb/tbb.h>
    #include <Windows.h>



    bool MyThread(int something)
    {
        std::cout << "This is a thread function\n" << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            something++;
            Sleep(1);
        }

        return true;
    }

    int main ()
    {
        tbb::tbb_thread pMyThread = tbb::tbb_thread(MyThread, 3);

        pMyThread.join();

        return 0;
    }
```

But if I compile it in VS 2008 it shows:
        error C2248: 'tbb::internal::tbb_thread_v3::tbb_thread_v3' : cannot access private                member declared in class 'tbb::internal::tbb_thread_v3'

for the first string of main() function. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Most thread objects, either tbb or c++11 cannot be copied or assigned. You code invoke an unnecessary assignment operator which is private to prevent you do exactly this. However C++11 thread are movable. Not sure if it is the case of tbb

Comment: the one in tbb\compat is I believe movable, however he is using vs2008 which doesn't have rvalue support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely calling a copy constructor when it shouldn't, try this instead:

```
tbb::tbb_thread myThread(MyThread, 3);
```

If you are able you should also consider using std::thread which is in the header

Comment: Why using `std::thread` if question is TBB related? I'm evaluating TBB for performance purposes and I'm curious about benchmarking it against `std::thread`s